# Как сделать чтоб exception не вылетало при нажатии на Button3?

Tags: c++

`Exception` вылетает вот здесь :

> B[(int)buff]=B[(int)buff]+1

Собственно сам код :

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button3Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    long m= 356896;
    long r=95,k=256,b=64,n,f;
    int buff,i,x;
    buff=0;
    double ri = 0;

    int B[10];

    n=StrToInt(Edit1->Text);
    float A[100];


    for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
    {

        ri=double((k*r+b)% m);

        r=ri;
        ri=ri/m;
        A[i]=ri;


        for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
        {
            Memo3->Lines->Add(A[i]);


            buff=A[i]*10+1;



            Memo4->Lines->Add((int)buff);
            *******B[(int)buff]=B[(int)buff]+1;*******

        }

        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {

            Series3->AddXY(i,B[i]/100);
        }
        Series4->AddXY(i,(double)random(n)/n);

    }
}
```

Comment: "при компиляции"??

Comment: а ну тут я ошибся ни при компиляции ,а когда я нажал на баттон

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, вы вообще не инициализируете массив `B`. Та же фигня и с `A` - в первом цикле вы едва успеваете инициализировать первый элемент, как тут же во втором используете весь массив. Есть у меня подозрение, что вложенный цикл (с тем же индексом!) - это не совсем то, что вы хотели.

А раз `A` не инициализирован, то в нем может быть что угодно. Значит, и в `buff` тоже что угодно - т.е. выход за пределы массива `B` (кстати, зачем вы приводите `int buff` к `int` же?) вам обеспечен...

Comment: int buff привожу к int для выделения целой части

Comment: @Credo Целой части из чего?! Из целого числа??

Comment: у меня в задании так написано ,что можно было сделать так, я и не подумав int воткнул ,ну вообще здесь int B[(int)buff]=B[(int)buff]+1 ненужен получается , он нужен только при инициализации buff.